# Object Incorrectly Showing Up As Reference?

Tags: c++, vector, llvm, llvm-c++-api

edited for clarity:

I have a vector of vectors, allPaths, and a single vector, path, that I am trying to add into allPaths. 
allPaths is passed by reference and path is passed by value into a function.

When trying to do

```
allPaths.insert(path);
```

I get the error that I can't add a reference to allPaths, even though path is a value:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<llvm::Instruction*> >::insert(std::vector<llvm::Instruction*>&)’
             allPaths.insert(path);
                             ^
```

allPaths is a `vector<std::vector<llvm::Instruction*>&`.
path is a `vector<llvm::Instruction*>`.

Why is the `path` argument showing up as a reference to the vector in the error instead of as the actual vector?

Any advice would be deeply appreciated! I am very new to both C++ and LLVM so some of my assumptions might also be incorrect.

Comment: Instead of the large explanation of your code, it's much better just posting [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) has no overload for one argument.

Did you mean [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead of `insert`?